# Cancel Button On Open File Dialog Doesn't Close Window For Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, openfiledialog, cancel-button

I am writing a window asking for a prompt to ask the user to save a file. It closes and asks if they want to overwrite a file, except when I press cancel it is still stuck in the while loop. Does anyone know the code for a cancel/close window?

```
Private Sub btn_Browse1_Click()

  Dim strFilter As String
Dim strOutputFileName As String, compareFileName As String, response As Integer, fileSet As Boolean

strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Excel Files (*.xlsx)", "*.xlsx")

fileSet = False
While fileSet = False
    strOutputFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                        Filter:=strFilter, _
                        OpenFile:=False, _
                        DialogTitle:="Choose an image file...", _
                        Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)


        If Len(strOutputFileName) > 0 Then
        compareFileName = Dir(strOutputFileName)
        If compareFileName <> "" Then 'find exist file with the same name
            response = MsgBox("The current file name already exists. Do you want to replace the file " & strOutputFileName & " with the current one?", vbYesNo)
            If response = vbYes Then
                fileSet = True      'replace old file
                Kill strOutputFileName
            Else
                fileSet = False
            End If
        Else 'no file exists with the same name
            fileSet = True
        End If

    End If
Wend
Me.txt_File_Level1.Value = strOutputFileName
```

Comment: I suggest you change your tags to include excel-vba and to remove vb.net

Answer (score 0):

your fileSet is equal to False in your else clause

```
If response = vbYes Then
    fileSet = True
Else
    fileSet = False
End If
```

I would first replace with a do/while loop because you can only exit prematurely with a GOTO statement if I remember correctly.

```
Dim strFilter As String
Dim strOutputFileName As String, compareFileName As String, response As Integer, fileSet As Boolean

strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Excel Files (*.xlsx)", "*.xlsx")

fileSet = False
Do While fileSet = False
    strOutputFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                    Filter:=strFilter, _
                    OpenFile:=False, _
                    DialogTitle:="Choose an image file...", _
                    Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)


    If Len(strOutputFileName) > 0 Then
        compareFileName = Dir(strOutputFileName)
        If compareFileName <> "" Then 'find exist file with the same name
            response = MsgBox("The current file name already exists. Do you want to replace the file " & strOutputFileName & " with the current one?", vbYesNo)
            If response = vbYes Then
                fileSet = True      'replace old file
                Kill strOutputFileName
            Else
                fileSet = False
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else 'no file exists with the same name
            fileSet = True
        End If
    End If
Loop
Me.txt_File_Level1.Value = strOutputFileName
```

Comment: Hmm... still seems to be popping up again after I press the cancel button. Sorry I am a rather novice with this.

Comment: even when replacing your while loop? are you in visual studio or using vba in access/excel?

Comment: VBA in AccessExcel

Comment: I can't test more since I don't have office near me but I think that changing your loop should resolve your problem since you're never exiting the loop when you click on _Cancel_ (else clause of `response = vbYes`) because fileSet is still set to `False`. I've updated my answer if you want to check it.